# How to create Price Filter with multiple conditions in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create an e-commerce website which has multiple filters.

I'm having trouble understanding the right way to apply numeric filters.

Here is the list of my filters for pricing a product:

0-500 USD

501-1000 USD

1001-5000 USD

5001-10000 USD

10000-20000 USD

20000+ USD

I tried `$and` with multiple price filter. User selects 0-500 & 1000-5000 filter

Query:

```
{
 "category":"jeans",
 "$and":
   [
     {"price":{"$gt":1000}},
     {"price":{"$lte":5000}},
     {"price":{"$gt":0}},
     {"price":{"$lte":500}}
   ]
}
```

I tried `$and` with array of `$or`.  User selects 0-500 & 1000-5000 filter

Query:

```
{
  "category":"jeans",
  "$and":
   [
    {"$or":[{"price":{"$gt":1000}},{"price":{"$lte":5000}}]},
    {"$or":[{"price":{"$gt":0}},{"price":{"$lte":500}}]}
   ]
}
```

I get incorrect results with both approaches.

What's the right approach here?

Comment: check your documents, are the prices in String or Integer? Common error are numbers not being stored as numbers.

Comment: I checked that, type is Number. `price: { type: Number }`

Comment: Then its because of your filter, since your filter will return 0 results. because the eventual price has to be greater than 1000, but less than 500, which is impossibile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return 0 results, because the product has to be greater than 1000, but less than 500, which is impossible.

```
{
 "category":"jeans",
 "$and":
   [
     {"price":{"$gt":1000}},
     {"price":{"$lte":5000}},
     {"price":{"$gt":0}},
     {"price":{"$lte":500}}
   ]
}
```

You may want to use

```
{
  "category":"jeans",
  "$or":
   [
    {"$and":[{"price":{"$gt":1000}},{"price":{"$lte":5000}}]},
    {"$and":[{"price":{"$gt":0}},{"price":{"$lte":500}}]}
   ]
}
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/dk7jqJ_qo1S

Comment: Awesome, I interchanged `$or` with `$and` it worked.